# Topology of the intersection of toric arrangement

Tags: general-topology, geometry, discrete-mathematics, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Hope someone will help me in the solution of the following question. I'm working on some topological problem involving the topology of the intersection of some characters of the torus. I want ot find a way to exstimate the dimension of a manifold using some matrix. Here's the question; probably it's a well known problem in the literature

Let $n\geq1$ and let $\mathcal{W}\subseteq(S^{1})^{n}$ be the space of solution of the system
$$z_{1}^{w_{1}^{1}}\cdots z_{n}^{{w_{1}^{n}}}=b_{1}$$
$$\cdots$$
$$z_{1}^{w_{m}^{1}}\cdots z_{n}^{{w_{m}^{n}}}=b_{m}$$

where $m\geq1,$ $w_{i}^{j}\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $1\leq i \leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$ and $b_{l}\in S^{1}$ for $1\leq l \leq m.$
Let $W\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{Z})$ be the matrix of $m$ rows and $n$ columns defined by 
$$W=(w_{i}^{j})$$
Then, $\mathcal{W}$ is either empty or a finite disjoint union of subtori of $(S^{1})^{n},$ each of dimension $\operatorname{dim}\ker(W).$